# let-c-curve-intersection-elliptical-cylinder-y-2z2-1-plane-x-1-oriented-counterclockwise

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

let c be the curve intersection elliptical cylinder y^2+2z^2=1 with the plane x=-1 oriented counterclockwise direction when viewed from far out the positive x axis. I need to find piecewise smooth parametrization of the curve c.

I normally go with y^2+2z^2-x=0 but it seems i did it wrong.

Comment: Can you explain where you think things went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What’s wrong with

$$(-1, \cos t , \frac12 \sin t)?$$

There’s something very wrong with what you “normally go for”.

Also, welcome to MSE!

Comment: First thank you for your comment. I was trying to use polar coordinates (which is not necessary) but i can see now it was a mistake.